# Set parameters of ESP8266 through Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

The problem is that I want to execute the code below, but when ESP8266 is shut down, then I start it again, everything is gone.
So, is there a solution that I can make this ESP8266 work the same controlled by my Arduino Uno.

My program blow is to control the GPIO2 through web browser.

Thanks a lot to all of you!!

**My Codes:**

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <aREST.h>

// Create aREST instance
aREST rest = aREST();

// WiFi parameters
const char* ssid = "Protect Big Dragon 4";
const char* password = "18717772056";

// The port to listen for incoming TCP connections 
#define LISTEN_PORT           80

// Create an instance of the server
WiFiServer server(LISTEN_PORT);

void setup(void)
{  
 // Start Serial
  Serial.begin(115200);

 // Give name and ID to device
  rest.set_id("2");
  rest.set_name("lamp_control");

 // Connect to WiFi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
   delay(500);
   Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}

void loop() {

  // Handle REST calls
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }
  rest.handle(client);

}
```

Comment: `everything is gone` anything more concrete? You mean the GPIO pins statuses don't have the same state again after a reboot? Then save the GPIO config to flash and read it out again after a reboot. `So, is there a solution that I can make this ESP8266 work the same controlled by my Arduino Uno?` Now you don't want it to be controlled by a webclient, but to be controlled via an Arduino? Your question is very unclear to me, please clarify.

Comment: I just mean that I need to upload again once I reboot the esp8266

Comment: Thank you Gerhardt

Comment: Sorry, mabe my description is not good. The reboot in my question means powering on Esp8266 Launcher again.

Comment: you need to make sure loop() has a delay; every time.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I’ve solved my problem. Once I power on again, the GPIO0 and the GPIO1 should be pull up.

Answer (score 0):

So your ESP8266 loses your code when it is rebooted.

Sounds like the memory is faulty.

Try a different ESP8266 and let us know what occurs.

Comment: Sorry, mabe my description is not good. The reboot in my question means powering on Esp8266 Launcher again.

Comment: Thanks you Richard. I’ve solved my problem. Once I power on again, the GPIO0 and the GPIO1 should be pull up.